# Is it possible to use google calendar api (java script) without having a server?

Tags: calendar, google-calendar-api

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/js

Above page mentions

To run this quickstart, you'll need:

1. Python 2.4 or greater (to provide a web server).
2. Access to the internet and a web browser.
3. A Google account with Google Calendar enabled.

I don't want to use webserver as mentioned in 1.

I want to display my own calendar by giving permission using oauth in a simple html page.

Comment: where do you intend to host the html page?   JavaScript can run within a html page.

Comment: not planning to host. it should load from my filesystem on a click.

Comment: that is doable not sure I would choose JavaScript thought

Comment: Any pointers to that ?  I cannot use gapi. it doesnt allow filesystem based calls from browser (without being hosted)

Comment: it doesn't?  Wonder why.  code the calls yourself I guess

Comment: https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/issues/46

yep I am not an expert in oauth/js.. Trying to get pointers towards that.

Comment: yup I agree with that post it won&#39;t work with the library.   probably won&#39;t work if you code it yourself.   try curl, php or python.